# I am getting an error on installing an msi file with wine

Tags: wine

I am trying to install the epic games launcher with wine on my Ubuntu 18.10, I have installed wine properly and when I run the code `msiexec /i EpicInstaller-9.7.0.msi`
I get an error saying

```
`ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.`
```

Comment: Not all Windows software can be installed using wine.

Comment: Does installation of [`libgtk3-nocsd0` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=cosmic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libgtk3-nocsd.so.0) with `sudo apt install   libgtk3-nocsd0 libgtk3-nocsd0:i386` fix the problem?

Comment: well, it no longer gives an error, but now the terminal thinks for a second and then just gives me a new command line. nothing happening in the background or anything. I think Pilot6 was right, not everything can be installed. though when googling the epic installer for linux I get bunches of fora that give me the same command `msiexec /i EpicInstaller-9.7.0.msi`